# Eclipse: getListView().setListAdapter(mAdapter);

Tags: android, eclipse

Eclipse complains about this line of code:

```
getListView().setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

saying:

```
The method setListAdapter(ToDoListAdapter) is undefined for the type ListView
```

It suggests:

1. changing `setListAdapter` to `setAdapter`
2. or using this next line of code:

   ListView ((ListActivity) getListView()).setListAdapter(mAdapter);

Is there anything better / clearer?

Comment: What does your activity extend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's either

`ListActivity.setListAdapter`

or

`ListView.setAdapter()`.

ListActivity's setListAdapter is a shortcut for

> ListActivity.getListView.setAdapter()

Answer (score 1):

It looks you are using `ListActivity`. Simply call call `setListAdapter()` on that activity.

Answer (score 1):

Your Activity must extend `ListActivity`. `setListAdapter` is a method of `ListActivity`. So you must be extending `ListAcitivity`

So change

```
getListView().setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

to

```
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

`ListView` does not have `setLiastAdapter`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#setListAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)

```
public void setListAdapter (ListAdapter adapter)

Added in API level 1
Provide the cursor for the list view.
```

And `getListView`

```
public ListView getListView ()

Added in API level 1
Get the activity's list view widget.
```